# I'm using mailto for my forms but when I try to submit the form absolutely nothing happens, am I missing something?

Tags: html, forms, email

I want to try a simple mailto for my form but it doesn't seem to be working. Once all the details have been added and the submit form is clicked nothing changes at all, it stays on the same page and nothing of the forms change. Am I missing anything? Any help is appreciated, thank you!

```html
<form class="form" id="form" action="mailto:example@gmail.com" method="POST" enctype="text/plain">
  <div class="form-control">
    <label for="namee">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="namee" name="name">
    <small>ERROR MESSAGE </small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-control">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email">  
    <small>ERROR MESSAGE </small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-control">
    <label for="phoneno">Phone Number</label>
    <input type="tel" id="phoneno" name="phoneno"> 
    <small>ERROR MESSAGE </small>
  </div>
  <button>SEND REQUEST</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Does that not invoke whatever mail client (Outlook, Pegasus, Thunderbird etc) you have installed? For me that launches Outlook and populates the `to` field

Comment: unfortunately no :((( thank you so much though I really appreciate it

Comment: If you do not have a mail client installed I'm not sure what application will be registered to handle those types of links. On windows you can configure which app opens these

Comment: ahhh right that is the issue, thank you so much again